# How can I refresh a window based on the message sent by an observer subject?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0, observer-pattern

I implemented the observer design pattern in my application, but my app sends to an remote server requests via http protocol that take some time to resolve.

So, naturally, I did the sending an receiving part in a separate thread.

Can you please tell me how to make an window that observes the RequestObject to modify it's state based on the state of the request?
In the debugger step by step mode the window runes the code that I want it to do, but the window never refreshes its self.

Comment: This does not sound very hard, just event stuff. But I don't fully understand what you want to do. Maybe you can add some code samples of what you've tried? or else tell in pseudo-code what you do want?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have a sample of your code I don't know the exacts of how you are updating your UI.  If you are attempting to update the UI in the seperate thread that could be your issue.  This may be of some help.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188732.aspx

You may also consider using the Task Parellel Library to perform your asyc operations.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx